# Setting the value of input in angular

Tags: html, angularjs, input

How can i set a value of input in agnular.It looks like this.Is there any method for that.

```
angular.element(idOfInput)
```

Comment: Angular 1 uses [jqLite](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element), you can do `angular.element('#' + idOfInput).val(value)`. But, I believe you're missing the advantage of using angular. Have a look at [two-way data binding](https://www.sitepoint.com/two-way-data-binding-angularjs/). And you might want to reconsider your approach.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to mark your input using `<input ... #myInput ... />`

And then use `@ViewChild('myInput') myInput: ElementRef;`
in your component and then you could use `this.myInput.nativeElement.value`.

But this basically sounds like a bad approach, I'd reconsider things, you could post your code and I'll comment what I think if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `ng-model` on the element, and set it to a variable that you then assign in the controller. Something like:

`<input ng-model="inputValue" />`

And then in your controller `$scope.inputValue = 'whateverValue'`.